# Term for pitting oppressed people against one another

Tags: oppression

What is the term for when an oppressor causes dissension among an oppressed group, with the aim of fomenting intra-group hostilities that will impede an effective rebellion? For example, if a slave owner treats some slaves better than others to create jealousy and disunity. I really thought there was a term for this but am not finding it.

Comment: That's a linguistic, not a historic question.

Comment: Not sure that history is the tool to answer this

Comment: "Sow dissension" seems to fit.

Comment: The English site sometimes fields these under the [single-word-requests tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)

Comment: "Divide and conquer"?

Comment: @paulgarrett ["Divide and rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule) may be more common historically

Comment: [divide et impera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule)